# ReactJS, deleting an item in parent.state in a child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m actually trying to use ReactJs that I find really fun and giving me a new way to approach my View problems.

But I m facing a problem when trying to delete an item in a child component :

- I have a parent component in which I initialize a list
- I pass this list to my child component which has to list it between '' tag
- I want to delete an item in this child with a button but I cant access the parent.state and so, I cant delete it (unidirectional binding with props)

How can I do to make it work properly ?

This is my code :

```
MyDirective = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        toReturn = {}
        toReturn.text = 'Hi';
        toReturn.stringList = [
            {id: 1, value: 'value 1'},
            {id: 2, value: 'value 2'},
            {id: 3, value: 'value 3'}
        ];
        return toReturn;
    },
    handleChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    },
    handleKeypress: function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code === 13) {
            this.setState({stringList: this.state.stringList.concat([
                {id: this.state.stringList.length + 1, value: this.state.text}
            ])})
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.handleKeypress} />
                <p>
                    {this.state.text}
                </p>
                <Listing stringList={this.state.stringList} />
            </div>
            );
    }
});


Listing = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function (item) {
        // I cant modify my state there :-/
    },
    render: function () {
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.stringList.map(function (item) {
                        return(
                            <li key={item.id}>{item.value}                    ->
                                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button>
                            </li>
                            );
                    }.bind(this))
                    }

            </ul>
            );
    }
});

React.render(
    <MyDirective text=""/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could look at reflux and its stores.
The idea behind this is storing your data in a different place where you can access it from any view that needs to do relevant changes.

your parent component in this case would "listen" to changes om the store (using eventEmitter) and update its state when changes in the store where made.

Hope this helped.